# Can I use the weigh paint information as color vertex information?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-colors, vertex-paint, vertex-weights

I've came up with a question regarding weight painting and color vertex data.
So this is the explanation to my question:

I would like to use the gradient I created as weight paint to create a mask with B&W information and use it in the node editor like when I create a color vertex data and re use it with the atribute COL in the node editor.

[image]

*I created a mask manually to show what I ideally want.*

Is there a way? thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well a few minutes after I posted the question here, I sent the question into a Slack Group and Julian Perez (@julper) found this great addon that fits exactly to what I was needing.

I will share what he found with you.

The addon is called [Weight-and-Color](https://github.com/chebhou/Weight-and-Color)

[image]

Comment: Seems it requires to be updated for 2.8+ unfortunately